# py2app 0.26 Black Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, py2app

I've just installed py2app 0.26 since I need the new SSL recipe, however, it appears to be displaying only a black Tkinter window upon launch.

Just seeing if anyone else is encountering this issue and if there have been any workarounds since py2app 0.26 has been released.

Comment: Could you file an issue on the py2app GitHub repo? Please include information about your python version and how it was installed.

Comment: The black window happens when combining a too old build of Tk with a new build of the main executable, py2app tries to detect the old Tk build and picks an older build of the main executable in that case, and may have made the wrong choice for you.  To fix that I need to know which python version and build you used, and possibly more information about Tkinter.

Comment: Thanks @RonaldOussoren, apologies if my question was vague, I'm still pretty new to programming in general. I'm running Python 3.9.6 (v3.9.6:db3ff76da1), tk 0.1.0 (according to pip3) and Tkinter version 8.6.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in py2app 0.26 in combination with the "Intel" variant of the Python.org installer for macOS.   The bug is fixed in py2app 0.26.1.